# Soon everything would / will

Tags: will-would

I have this part in a story, and I have no idea if it should be *would* or *will*:

> I looked at the Merrimack River, always so big and beautiful. On the riverbend, the trees started blossoming with the coming spring. Soon everything **would** be full of life and birds. But as of now, most trees still looked dead.

Answer (score 1):

'would' is correct here.

This sentence is [future-in-the-past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Future-in-the-past). 
 The rest of the paragraph is set in past tense, and this sentence describes what **would** happen looking from that past time into its future.

if the whole paragraph were changed to present tense, 'would' would change to 'will'.